# I have the error object are not valid as tract child (found object...) When i call a async function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I try to call Octokit api (github) to check if i follow the people who follows me.

There is my code:

```
followers.map((followers) =>{
                    return(
                      
                     <Text>
                   {followers.login}
                   <Text>
                    isFollowing?
                   </Text>
                   {checkisFollowing(followers.login)}
                   
...
```

and there is my function check is gollowing(fanfan)

```
  const checkisFollowing = async(fanfan) => {
    console.log(fanfan, "is following?")


    return("1")

  }
```

```
and it gives me the error
```

Objects are not valid as a React child (object with keys {_U, _V, _W, _X})

```
I already checked on internet but i don't find the solution.


Thanks for your answers!
```

Comment: `checkisFollowing` is async and will therefore return a promise. You can't render a promise in React. Somewhere in your code, you need to do an `await`.

Answer (score 1):

If the function is async and you are requesting something from API, you should have a state.
When `checkisFollowing` you should update the state, and on return you display the state value:

```
const [checkFollowingState, setCheckFollowingState] = useState("");

const checkisFollowing = async(fanfan) => {
    console.log(fanfan, "is following?")
    // so async work

    setCheckFollowingState("1")
  }

return (
 <Text>
   {checkFollowingState}
 </Text>
```

---

If you have multiple requests, you can do:

```
Promise.all([someAsyncRequest]).then(checkisFollowingArray => setCheckFollowingState(checkisFollowingArray))
...
return (
 <Text>
   {checkFollowingState[0]}
 </Text>
```

Comment: it doesn't change anything, where do i have to call my "checkisFollowing"?

Comment: `Promise.all(followers.map((ollowers =>checkisFollowing(followers.login)).then(...`